# Insert into One-to-One Relationship

Tags: mysql

My MySQL database contains two tables: `user` and `coupon` (one-to-one relationship).

I would like to select all users that do not have a coupon and create a new one (random and unique).

```
user TABLE:
___________________________________
|  id   |   name   |   coupon_id  |
-----------------------------------
   1        John         5
   2        Mary         (null)  // Need to create one coupon.
   3        Doe          2
   4        Max          (null)  // Need to create one coupon.
   5        Rex          1
   7        Bill         (null)  // Need to create one coupon.


coupon TABLE:
______________________________________________
|  id   |   code (random 6-chars - unique)   |
----------------------------------------------
   1        80k2ni
   2        0akdne
   5        nk03jd
```

---

Shortcuts:

Select all users without coupon: `SELECT * from user WHERE coupon_id IS NULL;`

Generate a random 6-chars string (MySQL): `LEFT(sha1(rand()), 6)`.

Comment: i have a feeling that you need to use [INSERT ... SELECT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-select.html) though i don't really have the setup to write up a mock query at the moment

Comment: @Memor-X Thank you for trying to help, but I have not figured out how to make it work. Please write it when you have time ;)

Comment: `SELECT u.is,u.name,COALESCE(u.coupon_id ,LEFT(sha1(rand()), 6))     FROM user u LEFT JOIN coupon c on u.coupon_id  =c.id` Maybe you want this query it`s not very clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you don't mind continuing upwards from 6 for the next `coupon_id`, this can be done as follows (see [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/71cc2)):

```
-- Declare and set variables
SET @id_for_insert = (SELECT MAX(`id`) FROM `coupon`);
SET @id_for_update = @id_for_insert;

-- Insert new coupons
INSERT INTO `coupon` (id, code)
SELECT @id_for_insert := @id_for_insert + 1, LEFT(SHA1(RAND()), 6)
FROM `user`
WHERE coupon_id IS NULL;

-- Update users that don't already have a coupon with the newly created coupons
UPDATE `user`
SET coupon_id = @id_for_update := @id_for_update + 1
WHERE coupon_id IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe:

```
Insert into coupon 
select distinct id,LEFT(sha1(rand()), 6) 
from user WHERE coupon_id IS NULL
```

After this, you can update coupon in user table using simple update with join.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand what you try to explain. Running this code I get `Column count doesn't match value count at row 1`.

Comment: My code is solely based on the information given by you and is untested. So if there are additional columns in the coupon table, you will have to add them to the select clause as well.

Comment: Thanks, now its creating the entries into `coupon` table. But how can I insert the `coupon_id` in the `user` table?

Comment: Simple update like this should work: `update u set u.coupon_id=c.id from user u join coupon c on u.id= c.id where u.coupon_id is null`

Comment: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from user u join coupon c on u.id= c.id where u.coupon_id is null' at line 1`

Answer (score 0):

```
//check if works inform me i will be glad
CREATE PROCEDURE `syncCouponUser` ()
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO coupon(id,code)//create coupons var no-used user ids
    select
    id,
    LEFT(sha1(rand())
    from user
    where coupon_id IS NULL ;

     UPDATE user //add coupons from coupon table with matches
    SET coupon_id=(
    select c.coupon_id
    from coupon c join user u 
    on c.id=u.id);

END
```